# How to find Designated Pilot Examiners (DPE)s?

Tags: checkride, designated-examiner

I took my first private pilot exam three weeks ago, and schedule a re-take with the  Designated Pilot Examiner (DPE) for next week. Except this week, he called and cancelled. :(

I've called and texted every DPE in the state of Utah, trying to make any appointment within the FAA's 60-day window for a retake. (https://designee.faa.gov/ though there's a fair number listed that only do other stuff, like helicopters)

No responses. What should I do?

Do I look at other states? My instructor doesn't want me to have my exam at an unfamiliar airport, but I don't see what the other options are? Do I figure out alternative ways of contact (home addresses?) Do I talk to the FSDO? Is there someone "in charge"?

Is there someone that can help me? I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT: Rescheduled with another DPE, and then he canceled day-of. :/

Comment: Call your local FSDO, ask for an Operations Inspector and explain your circumstances.  Also, your instructor should be helping you with this issue.  I can't imagine it would be a significant issue to resolve so you can take the retest within the 60 window.

Comment: @RTO Unfortunately my instructor is on vacation, and only somewhat available. Pilots seems to have ... erratic ... schedules.

Comment: Call the FSDO and explain your issue. Ask to speak to an Operations Inspector and they should be able to help.

Comment: @RTO thanks I appreciate it.

Comment: What state are you in?